# Standalone components and module-level singleton providers

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

I'm trying to bring together my current modular design and standalone components, but have a hard time with singleton service providers.

My old layout used to have a separate module for each... well module :) of the application, declaring the components required for the application-module (let's call it feature for simplicity sake), and the providers declared by said feature.

Say I had a feature-module called 'users', that included the new, edit, update pages (components), and declared a provider for the `UsersService` which was responsible for making the correct API calls and keeping client-side state in sync with server-side state via "manual" refreshing after each modification request. This service needs to be a singleton, since the state is global. The feature module was then lazy-loaded from the root router:

```
  { path: 'users', loadChildren: () => import('modules/users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule) },
```

For encapsulation and housekeeping purposes the intent is NOT to use `{ providedIn: 'root' }`, so other feature-modules wouldn't be able to fiddle with the `usersService`.

Now, my first approach was to get rid of the `users.module` altogether, but then there was no provider for the `usersService`

Okay, that makes sense, added the `usersService` as provider for both components, but then the two injected instances were not the same, and their states went out of sync depending on where it got updated.

The next approach was to bring back the `users.module`, that imports and exports the page components, and provides the service. The idea was that they would inherit the provider, and it will provide The application-level router was not going to import the components, but rather the `users.module`, and use the components exported by that. The super weird thing is that for the index page, it works, but when the index page creates a dialog for creating a new `user`, the `userService` cannot be injected:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[UsersNewDialog])[UsersService -> UsersService -> UsersService]:
```

Importing the `UsersModule` from the `UsersNewDialog` does not work (cyclic dependency).

Looking at the angular injector tree, the weird thing is that I can see the `Standalone[UsersIndexPage]` under the `UsersModule`, but not the one for the `UsersNewDialog`. If I remove the dependency on the `UsersService`, I can see the `Standalon[UsersNewDialog]` showing up, but it is NOT nested under the `UsersModule`. Could this be because the dialog is created nested under the `<body>` and not the `UsersIndexPage`? But that doesn't really make sense either, the `UsersIndexPage` inherits the `UsersModule`'s providers, so why shouldn't the `UsersNewDialog` as well?

Not sure what the correct layout would be in this case.